Converting a 3d model into a square-dominant mesh with same sized faces
I need to create a quad-dominant mesh for a 3d model such that all quads are approximately squares and all non-quads are triangles. An additional requirement is that all square faces have to be close to the same size. Below is an image example. I haven't been able to find a solution to this exact problem. I just want to know if it is possible, since I am brand new to Blender. Any help is appreciated.


The tool that comes the closest to what you show is probably the Data > Remesh > Quad, click on the QuadriFlow Remesh button and you'll be able to choose the amount of faces in the pop-up panel:

Result with 2000 faces:

But a software like Instant Meshes, tutorial here by SouthernGFX, will do it a bit better, for example you'll be able to choose the topology flow:

Result (quickly made so it's largely improvable):

